# How to use Data Annotations when You are submitting form using Ajax Call in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I am using JS to submit the form but I want to validate one filed in that form I applied annotations in the model but these annotations are not showing on the page instead of that exception is throwing because annotation is working but the form is submitted due to Ajax call.
Can someone please help me?

```
<form id="share">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="container col-md-12">
        <table id="myTable" class="cell-border compact hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().Id)</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().TagName)</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().TagCategory)</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.tags.First().TagValue)</th>
                    <th style="text-align:center"> Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.tags.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].Id)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.tags[i].Id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagCategory)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "TagVaule_" + Model.tags[i].Id, @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.tags[i].TagValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="UpdateRow(@Model.tags[i].Id)">Update</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content" id="myModalContent">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="BulkUpdate()">BulkUpdate</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
        });

           function BulkUpdate()
           {
               debugger;
                   var form= $("#share");
                   $.ajax({
                   type: 'GET', //GET
                   url: '@Url.Action("BulkUpdate", "Home")',
                   data: form.serialize(),
                   success: function (data) {
                       debugger;
                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                   }
               });

            }
        //BulkUpdate Confirmation
         function BulkConfirm()
         {
             var form= $("#share");
                $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST', //GET
                   url: '@Url.Action("BulkUpdateConfirmation", "Home")',
                   data: form.serialize()
                });
                $("#myModal").modal('hide')
            }

        //Single row update
        var RowId = 0;
        var tagvalue = 0;
            function UpdateRow(id)
            {
                tagvalue = $("#TagVaule_" + id).val();
                RowId=id;
                DisplayModal();
            }

            function DisplayModal()
            {

                 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                     url: '@Url.Action("Update","Home")',
                    data: {
                        id: RowId,
                        value: tagvalue
                    },
                    success: function(data)
                {
                    debugger;
                    $('#myModalContent').html(data);
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }
                });

            }
            function Confirm()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("SaveUpdate","Home")',
                    data: {
                        id: RowId,
                        value: tagvalue
                    },
                });
                $("#myModal").modal('hide')
            }

    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddStudent()
        {
            var student = new Student();

            // The TryUpdateModel will use data annotation to validate
            // the data passed over from the client. If any validation
            // fails, the error will be written to the "ModelState".
            var valid = TryUpdateModel(student);

            string studentPartialViewHtml = null;
            if (valid)
            {
                // Add the student to the repository.
                // In any pratical application, exception handling should be used
                // when making data access. In this small example, I will just cross
                // my finger to say "there is no chance to encounter exeption" when
                // adding the student. Indeed, the chance of exception is very minimal
                // when adding students to my small repositoty. If the validation is
                // successful, I will simply tell the client that the student is added.
                StudentRepository.AddStudent(student);

                // Obtain the html string from the partial view "Students.ascx"
                var students = StudentRepository.GetStudent();
                studentPartialViewHtml = RenderPartialViewToString("Students", students);
            }

            return Json(new {Valid = valid,
                             Errors = GetErrorsFromModelState(), 
                StudentsPartial = studentPartialViewHtml
            });
        }
```

The TryUpdateModel method takes a student object. It reads the data sent to the server from the Request object and tries to update the properties in the student object by matching the property name and the name of the posted data.
After the student object is updated, it will check the Data Annotations in the Student class to validate the data. If a problems is found, it will add the error message to the ModelState object of the controller. The return type of the TryUpdateModel method is Boolean indicating if the model was successfully validated.

```
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: addStudentUrl,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                // There is no problem with the validation
                if (data.Valid) {
                    $("#divStudent").html(data.StudentsPartial);
                    $("input").val("");
                    return;
                }

                // Problem happend during the validation, display
                // the messages. The following script will display the last
                // message related to the field.
                $.each(data.Errors, function (key, value) {
                    if (value != null) {
                        $("#Err_" + key).html(value[value.length - 1].ErrorMessage);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                alert("Critical Error!. Failed to call the server.");
            }
        })
```

For Detail You can follow this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/216439/Data-Validation-Using-Annotations-for-jQuery-Ajax)